# Date_format not working when inserting data into a table? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it valid to do this to change the date format while inserting data?

```
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO articles (id, title, content, publicationDate) VALUES ('NULL', '".$title."', '".$content."', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b, %e, %Y'))";
```

If not, how do I change the default date format (which is currently year-month-day)?

Answer (score 1):

the format you use to insert is not related to the format you get when selecting.

you can choose the format of the date column in the SELECT by using

```
TO_CHAR( publicationDate, 'yyyy mm/dd' )
```

or whatever format you like.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Randy,more over "Date" is a Data type defined in MySQL whose format cannot be changed.instead change it the way you want while u retrieve it in your query..

but 1 issue with the Date Data type is, every time you insert the date you have to give it in the yyyy-mm-dd format,if you find that weird,then i suggest you use a string datatype and form your queries accordingly.but of course i.e only if your database queries don't have any significant need of Publication Date attribute